# Cordova can't click input

Tags: html, ios, cordova

I've built several Cordova apps before and have usually linked the 'index.html' to an 'app.html' after authentication using `window.location = app.html`

In my latest app, when I logout of my application (clicking a button in app.html), I get redirected correctly to my index.html, but once I'm there, I cannot click any of the form inputs to try to log back in. The only way I can get it to work is by closing and reopening the app again.

Also to add, the posted code works fine if I run the html pages straight through safari or chrome but I cannot click those inputs when running on the iOS sim

```js
        access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        user_id = localStorage.getItem('user_id')

        if(access_token != undefined && user_id != undefined) {
            window.location = 'app.html'
        }

        $("#login-form").submit(function(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault()

                data = $(this).serialize()

                $.ajax({
                    method: "post",
                    url: 'https://*******.io/api/login',
                    data: data,
                    success:function(result) {
                        token_object = JSON.parse(result)
                        localStorage.setItem('access_token', token_object.access_token);
                        localStorage.setItem('user_id', token_object.user_id);
                        window.location = 'app.html'
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        401: function() {
                            $("#error-container").removeClass('hidden').html('Email/Password combination was not found.');
                        },
                        500: function() {
                            $("#error-container").removeClass('hidden').html('A server error has occured');
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


        <!-- Javascripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-loadtemplate.js"></script>
        <title>MyApp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- 3. Display the application -->
        <div class="container container-fluid login-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <h1 class="text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                        My App
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <form id="login-form">
                        <div id="error-container" class="form-group hidden"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email"  class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                        <button class="btn btn-default">
                            <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Not enough here to work with.  Please provide some code/error logs

Comment: Okay, are there any accompanying console logs/errors? For it to just stop working, it sounds like something broke

Comment: No errors in the xcode console or safari console when I debug the simulator. Also, the thing that throws me off even more is if I remove the <h1> </h1> that is around 'My App', the input fields start working again after redirecting back to my index.html.

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual device? The simulator isn't as reliable as I've wanted it to be for cordova development.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. The issue first cropped up to my company on real devices.

I'd hate to have to change the formatting of the page just to workaround this bug, but that may have to be the case. It feels super dirty to do that though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112713/discussion-between-bertmaclin-and-theaccordance).